# To store a contact into the json file from server.js file using a class in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have created three files -contactPresentation.js, contactService.js, contacts.json. I will run the contactService.js file. And it will navigate to  contactPresentation.js file that will only choose an option to either add or display a file. If add(), then add the data into add of service file.And the data will be added to the contacts.json file . And if display(), then display the display() of service file. And the display will take the data from contacts.json file. However, i know my code is flawed. Please correct it . I am also getting an error -

```
        this.contacts.push(new ContactService(userName, contactNumber, emailId));
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at ContactService.add (e:\NodeJSProject\contactManager2\contactService.js:57:23)
    at new ContactService (e:\NodeJSProject\contactManager2\contactService.js:31:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\NodeJSProject\contactManager2\contactService.js:96:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
```

**contactService.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

var uuid = require('uuid');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');



console.log(uuid.v1());

eval(fs.readFileSync('contactPresentation.js').toString())

class ContactService {

    constructor(userName, contactNumber, emailId) {


        uuidv1();
        this.id = uuid.v1();
        this.firstName = userName;
        this.contactNo = contactNumber;
        this.email = emailId;
        this.add(userName, contactNumber, emailId)
    }

    get UUID() {  
        return this.id;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    get contact() {
        return this.contactNo;
    }

    get emailID() {
        return this.email;
    }
    display() {

        loadFromFile();
        return this.contacts;
    }

    add(userName, contactNumber, emailId) {

        this.contacts.push(new ContactService(userName, contactNumber, emailId));

        saveToFile();

    }

    saveToFile() {

        let data = [];

        data.push(JSON.stringify(this.contacts, null, 2));

        fs.writeFile('contacts.json', data, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Data written to file');
        });

        console.log('This is after the write call');

    }

    loadFromFile() {   

        fs.readFile('contacts.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            var contact = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("contacts", contact);
        });

        console.log('This is after the read call');
    }

}

var test = new ContactService("abc",900, "abc@cateina.com");

test.display();
module.exports = ContactService
```

**contactPresentation.js**

```
contactService = require('./contactService.js')
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');


var option = readlineSync.question(`What would you like to do, Add or Display Contact.
For Add , type 1, for display type 2 `);


class ContactPresentation {

    constructor(option) {

        abc = true;
        createService = new ContactService();


        while (abc) {
            if (option == 1) {


                var userName = readlineSync.question('May I have your name? ');

                console.log('Hi ' + userName + '!');

                var contactNumber = readlineSync.question('May I have your contact number');

                var emailId = readlineSync.questionEMail();

                createService.add(userName, contactNumber, emailId);

            }
            else if (option == 2) {
                createService.display();
            }

        }
    }
}

module.exports = ContactPresentation;
```

**contacts.json**

```
 []
```

Comment: `eval(fs.readFileSync('contactPresentation.js').toString())` why are you `eval`ing instead of requiring, importing,??

Comment: i just put that piece of code to navigate to contactPresentation.js file so that  contactService.js file starts its wrking from Presentation file

Comment: Your code have circular dependency contact service depends on contact  person and vice versa and `evaling` isn't a good idea.

Comment: yeah. So how do i start from service.js file and end up displaying the content of Presentation file first

Answer (score 1):

You have To déclare

```
this.contacts = [];
```

In your contactService constructor.

And also, to start do what you asked in comment, your index.js would look like :

```
const ContactPresentation = require('contactPresentation.js');
const ContactService = require('contactService.js');

// to run contactPresentation
const cp = new ContactPresentation();

// to run display the content of Presentation file
var test = new ContactService("abc",900, "abc@cateina.com");
test.display();
```

Of course, you need to remove the 'eval' line, var test line and test.display line from contactPresentation.js

That's as simple as that.

Comment: after adding it, i get error -     bth[buf[i++]], bth[buf[i++]]]).join('');
                                                                                          

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: I don't understand why you use an eval instead of a require. And also, contactService.js don't need contactPresentation reference. I'd create an index.js including all the needed references, I won't run contactPresentation from contactService.js